# Spring boot Show Error with tomcat 8 connection pool Too many open files

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, connection-pool

Anybody may be help?

I have app that I bilt In Spring Boot whith externa Tomcat 8 using connection pool in context.xml.

But when I call with threads show me error after few minutes.

Look my code and configuration:

TKS 4ALL!!!

**context.xml**

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/ocp-api" auth="Container"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  maxTotal="150"
                    max-active= "100" 
                   max-idle= "80"
                    min-idle="8"
                    maxWaitMillis="2000"
                    username="postgres" 
                    password="postgres" 
                    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                    url="jdbc:postgresql://<myIpServer>:5432/db_ocp_ago2017"/>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/ocp-api



spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.application.name=ocp-api
server.contextPath=/ocp-api
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
spring.jackson.joda-date-time-format=yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.com.mkyong=DEBUG


# Logging pattern for the console
logging.pattern.console= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"

# Logging pattern for file
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"

logging.file=/var/supportcomm/ocp/log/ocp-api.log
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
```

> 26-Jul-2018 16:40:29.049 WARNING
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp Failed to
>   retrieve JNDI naming context for container
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ocp-api]]
>   so no cleanup was performed for that container
>
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [comp].
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:824)
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
>           at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:993)
>           at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5551)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1395)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1581)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:284)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1376)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1380)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1348)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "2018-07-26 16:51:27 - Cannot forward to error page for request
>   [/occupation] as the response has already been committed. As a result,
>   the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is
>   running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve
>   this problem by setting
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
>   "org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException:
>   java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:345)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:320)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:110)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1054)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:607)
>           at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286)
>           at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:124)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:118)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
>           at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:491)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
>           ... 66 common frames omitted
>
> 26-Jul-2018 16:52:20.989 SEVERE [http-nio-8280-Acceptor-0]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run Socket accept
>   failed java.io.IOException: Too many open files
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
>           at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:693)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> [pool-24-thread-14] WARN
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0,
>   SQLState: 08001"2018-07-26 16:52:32 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
>   2018-07-26 16:52:32 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 2018-07-26 16:52:32
>   - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 2018-07-26 16:52:32 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 2018-07-26 16:52:32 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
>   2018-07-26 16:52:32 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 2018-07-26 16:52:33
>   - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /vol/app/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/webapps/ocp-api/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
>   (Too many open files) 2018-07-26 16:52:34 -
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /vol/app/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/webapps/ocp-api/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
>   (Too many open files) 2018-07-26 16:52:34 -
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /vol/app/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/webapps/ocp-api/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
>   (Too many open files)

Comment: tomcat version?

Comment: use greater than 8.5

Comment: my tomcat is 8.0.38